# Which is more efficient: string concatenation or substitution?

Tags: php, microbenchmark

I am trying to make my program as little server-intensive as possible.
Would it be better to use double quotes and include the variable or use single quotes and use . to connect the variables?

For example,

```
$string = 'Hello ' . $first_name;
$string_two = "Hello $first_name";
```

Which way would be faster? I understand this is minimal, but I think this will help me figure out more about how PHP works internally.

Comment: benchmark it yourself.

Comment: I'd expect no difference. The PHP parser can tell that they're equivalent and should generate the same code.

Comment: really want to understand how php works internally? go read the source code.

Comment: When you bring us a question that has suppositions, your suppositions should be reflected by data. Show us your benchmark, your inputs, what your outputs were.  Then ask us.  Don't say "This is marginally faster than that, should I use it?" without showing us the benchmarks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got curious, so... Though OP: You can figure this out with the right question.

```
<?php

$a = 'YES';

$start_time = microtime(TRUE);
$test = "Yow $a";
echo $test . "\n";
$end_time = microtime(TRUE);
echo $end_time - $start_time;

echo "\n\n";

$start_time = microtime(TRUE);
$test = 'Yow ' . $a;
echo $test . "\n";
$end_time = microtime(TRUE);
echo $end_time - $start_time;

echo "\n\n";
```

Outputs:

1st run:

```
Yow YES
4.1007995605469E-5

Yow YES
6.9141387939453E-6
```

2nd run:

```
Yow YES
4.3869018554688E-5

Yow YES
8.8214874267578E-6
```

So using single quote then concatenate is better.

Comment: Plain and simple, and didn't have to be an as* about it. Nice answer.

Comment: there's a site that has all theses micro optimizations benchmarked for php, http://www.phpbench.com/

Comment: Woah, didn't know that one! Thanks @Dagon

Comment: @Dagon Unfortunately, it doesn't have a section for this.

Comment: I put your tests in a loop that runs 1 million times. My results were very inconsistent: sometimes the substitution loop took 1 second longer, sometimes the concatenation loop took 1 second longer.

Comment: @Barmar you are right about the inconsistency and I don't have an explanation for that. But I truly believe that concatenation with single quote is faster since there won't be any interpretation.